# How to install Debian From Live Cd

Tags: debian, system-installation, livecd

I downloaded Debian live CD from http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/debian-cd/9.4.0-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/ and afterwards I tried to install with following statement: `sudo debian-installer-launcher`
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there not an installation launcher on the Desktop?

Comment: No, it is nothing on the desktop.

Comment: When you first boot you should see a "Main Menu" which offers the Installation option.

Answer (score 2):

Before Debian 10, the live session did not have an installer included. That is why you do not see the installer icon on the desktop and in the [dash](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-introduction.html.en#activities) in GNOME (where Calamares installer in Debian 10 is) and cannot launch it from terminal. The only way to start installation in Debian 9.4.0 "stretch" is to choose an "Installer" option instead of the "Live" option in the "Main Menu" when you boot the CD. Once in the live session, you can reboot to get there.

It is possible to specifically make a Debian image with the `debian-installer-launcher`, but [it was not enabled by default](https://live-team.pages.debian.net/live-manual/html/live-manual/customizing-installer.en.html):

> **"Desktop" Debian Installer**: Regardless of the type of Debian Installer included, `d-i` can be launched from the Desktop by clicking on an icon. This is user friendlier in some situations. In order to make use of this, the debian-installer-launcher package needs to be included.
>
> Note that by default, *live-build* does not include Debian Installer images in the images, it needs to be specifically enabled with `lb config`. Also, please note that for the "Desktop" installer to work, the kernel of the live system must match the kernel `d-i` uses for the specified architecture.